# Isomorphic quotient rings of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wish to know if $$\dfrac{\mathbb Z_2[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]}{\langle x_1x_3,x_2x_4,x_1+x_3,x_2+x_3+x_4\rangle}\cong\dfrac{\mathbb Z_2[a,b]}{\langle a^3,b^2,a^2-ab\rangle}.$$

**Context** - I was computing the cohomology ring of the Klein bottle with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients using the result of Davis and Januszkiewicz ([Theorem 4.14 page 23](https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/old_papers/DJ_toric.dmj.pdf)) and obtained the first ring (LHS). The second ring (RHS) is what is known to be the cohomology ring of the Klein bottle. So they must be isomorphic. But I am unable to show that they are isomorphic.

I got as far as proving that the LHS is $\dfrac{\mathbb Z_2[x,y,z]}{\langle x^2,x+y+z,yz\rangle}$, but not sure how to go from there. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually consider the ideal $I:=(b^2, a^2-ab)\in \mathbb{Z}_2[a,b]$. Then
$$
a^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab)+ab^2\in I
$$
Then the RHS ring is in fact $\mathbb{Z}_2/(b^2, a^2-ab)$. The LHS ring (simplified version) is $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y,z]/(x^2, x+y+z, yz)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x^2, y(x+y))$. Also since the base ring is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you have $x^2-xy=x^2+xy$, and the two sides are the same.

**Edit**: You can take the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y,z]/(x^2, x+y+z, yz)\to \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x^2, y^2+yx)$ given by
$$
f(x,y,z)+(x^2, x+y+z, yz)\mapsto f(x,y,x+y)+(x^2, y^2+xy)
$$
You can easily check that this is well-defined and surjective. For injectivity note that
$$
f(x,y, z)+ (x^2, x+y+z, yz)= f(x,y, x+y)+ (x^2, x+y+z, yz)
$$
Now if $f(x,y,x+y)\in (x^2, y^2+xy)$, then
$$
f(x,y,x+y)=h_1(x,y)x^2+h_2(x,y)y(x+y)=
h_1(x,y)x^2+h_2(x,y)y(x+y+z)+h_2(x,y)yz\in (x^2, x+y+z+yz)
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y,z]/(x^2, x+y+z, yz)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x^2, y(x+y))$? I don't see it easily. Thank you.

Comment: @Rise In the left hand side ring of your comment the coset of $z$ is the same as the coset of $x+y$. So it is not needed as a generator, as we can use $x+y$ in its place everywhere.